# Local Storage not removing object in array when called, using the localStorage.remove method

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm building a movie watch list that stores movies in my local storage, and removes them. Here are the two CodePens for my code, one which searches & adds:

https://codepen.io/vanessalearnsjavascript/pen/vYVJPgm?editors=0011

And the other which is the "Watch List" page that removes:

https://codepen.io/vanessalearnsjavascript/pen/YzJEQEW?editors=0011

```
    removeMovieButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf(movie), 1);
      movieDiv.parentNode.removeChild(movieDiv);
      localStorage.removeItem("movie" + watchList.indexOf(movie));
    });
```

On the WatchList page, I have a "Remove Movie" button rigged up that removes the movie from the array and from the DOM, but the local storage of it does not work. Here is the removeMovie button, with the local storage line that is not executing. I can press the button and it removes the item from the array and the DOM, but when I have the local storage open, it remains.

Can anyone explain how I can fix this and why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: why are you not just storing an array in one entry??? No weird state management or variables.

Comment: I plan to do refactor the entire project to do that soon, honestly.

Comment: log ` watchList.indexOf(movie)` to the console, when testing with your codepen it outputs `-1` so it does not find the movie in watchlist

Answer (score 1):

you have just to change the execution orders, so replace this

```
 removeMovieButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf(movie), 1); // <-------- 1
      movieDiv.parentNode.removeChild(movieDiv);
      localStorage.removeItem("movie" + watchList.indexOf(movie)); // <------ 2
    });
```

by

```
 removeMovieButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      localStorage.removeItem("movie" + watchList.indexOf(movie)); // < ---- 2
      movieDiv.parentNode.removeChild(movieDiv);
      watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf(movie), 1);// < ---- 1
    });
```

*Explanation:* you are deleting the movie from the array then you are getting a wrong index of the "already" deleted item to remove it from localStorage, that's why it did not work for you .

Answer (score 1):

Why does it not work? You remove the item and then you try to find that item once again. Are you going to find it after it is removed?

```
removeMovieButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf(movie), 1); <-- You remove the entry
      movieDiv.parentNode.removeChild(movieDiv);
      localStorage.removeItem("movie" + watchList.indexOf(movie)); <-- you look for it again
    });
```

Now you can store the index into  variable, but when you remove the index, all of the other entries move down one. So that means `movie4` in the array would be at index 3, not 4. So you would have to adjust all of your local storage keys.

Just store the array!

```
watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf(movie), 1);
localStorage.setItem('watchList', JSON.stringify(watchList));
```

when you need the watch list, read it

```
watchList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('watchList') || '[]');
```